# GD Library - Detecting colors and shapes, advice?

Tags: php, gd

I have an image. Somewhere within this image is a rectangular box... Let's say it's 300px X 100px. It has a red border around it. I would like to be able to crop this image so that only the red box and the nearby area is left.

Is it possibly to do this programmatically with PHP and GD? Can anyone provide me with some pointers on where to get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php to load an image and get a single pixels color.

count all the black pixels
count all the black pixels from region 3
now you can calculate region 2 and also region 1

to count all the black pixels form region 3 just go trough each line. if everything is black, count everything. if not, count from left and from right all black pixels.

probably a better way todo it would be html5 canvas